# Code igniter session_start not working

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a codeigniter site , and for the past day it encountered a problem without any code modifications . It says :

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_5f9c0f8499f8970f68b2d94c92621af6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Although there is a `/tmp` in the root .

Additionally i given this in the config.php upon searching the issue .

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'tmp/';
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: did you change an permissions on `temp` directory??

Comment: yes i changed to 777

Comment: what's the `session.save_path` in `php.ini`?

Comment: goto php ini and set `ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');` after change restart your apache.

Comment: I am on cpanel , and have no backend access to check php.ini . BTW why its downvoted ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the "/" in the "BASEPATH".

Example "BASEPATH . '/tmp/';

Comment: More like comment.